# the bytes type in python 2.7 and PEP-358

Tags: python, types

According to [PEP 358](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0358/), a bytes object is used to store a mutable sequence of bytes (0-255), raising if this is not the case.

However, my python 2.7 says otherwise

```
>>> bytes([1,2,3])
'[1, 2, 3]'
>>> bytes([280])
'[280]'
>>> bytes is str
True
>>> bytes
<type 'str'>
```

Does anyone have a clue on the reason why the PEP is declared Final, but the implementation does not conform ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `bytes` type was introduced in Python 3, but what's being discussed in the PEP is a mutable sequence (`bytes` is immutable) which was introduced in Python 2.6 under the name `bytearray`.

The PEP clearly wasn't implemented as stated (and it does say that it was partially superseded by [PEP 3137](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3137/)) but I think it's only a question of things being renamed, not features missing. In Python 2 `bytes` is just an alias for `str` to aid forward compatibility and so is a red-herring here.

Example bytearray usage:

```
>>> a = bytearray([1,2,3])
>>> a[0] = 5
>>> a
bytearray(b'\x05\x02\x03')
```

Comment: 3137 as far as I see is for python 3, same topic, but I havent' read it yet.

Comment: bytearray was one of the new 3.0 features that was back-ported for 2.6 if I remember correctly.

Comment: @StefanoBorini You should have looked ate below answer.

Answer (score 54):

The new `bytes` **type** is **3.x only**. The 2.x `bytes` built-in is just an alias to the `str` type. There is no new type called `bytes` in 2.x; Just a new alias and literal syntax for `str`.

Here's the [documentation snippet](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3112-byte-literals) everybody loves:

> *Python 2.6 adds `bytes` as a synonym for
>   the `str` type, and it also supports the
>   `b''` notation.*
>
> ***The 2.6 `str` differs from 3.0’s bytes
>   type in various ways; most notably,
>   the constructor is completely
>   different. In 3.0, `bytes([65, 66, 67])`
>   is 3 elements long, containing the
>   bytes representing `ABC`; in 2.6,
>   `bytes([65, 66, 67])` returns the
>   12-byte string representing the `str()`
>   of the list.***
>
> *The primary use of `bytes` in 2.6 will
>   be to write tests of object type such
>   as `isinstance(x, bytes)`. This will
>   help the `2to3` converter, which can’t
>   tell whether 2.x code intends strings
>   to contain either characters or 8-bit
>   bytes; you can now use either `bytes` or
>   `str` to represent your intention
>   exactly, and the resulting code will
>   also be correct in Python 3.0.*

Comment: good answer, and indeed explains the effects, but it did not explain the lack of adherence to the PEP, hence I marked Scott as correct, and upvote you.

Comment: python 3.x has bytes as a new type while in python2.x bytes is str type itself .. well highlighted.

Answer (score 4):

`bytes` objects only really exist in Python 3.x.  `bytes` is an alias for str in Python 2.7.  It exists to help writing portable code between Python 2 and 3.