# Is it normal for python's io.BytesIO.getvalue() to return str instead of bytes?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it normal for python's `io.BytesIO.getvalue()` to return str instead of bytes?

```
 Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 13 2011, 14:28:51) 
 >>> import io
 >>> a = io.BytesIO()
 >>> a
 <_io.BytesIO object at 0x10f9453b0>
 >>> a.getvalue()
 ''
 >>> print type(a.getvalue())
 <type 'str'>
 >>>
```

Should I file a bug?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, this isn't a bug. This is normal behaviour. See this answer: [the bytes type in python 2.7 and PEP-358](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901706/the-bytes-type-in-python-2-7-and-pep-358)

It basically comes down that the 2.7 `bytes` is just an alias for `str` to smoothen the transition to 3.x.

Answer (score 4):

`bytes` doesn't exist as a separate kind of datastructure in Python 2.X so yes, it is entirely normal - `str` are bytestrings in Python 2 (unlike Python 3, where `str` are unicode strings).