# Python 3 - on converting from ints to 'bytes' and then concatenating them (for serial transmission)

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, type-conversion, byte

After much fruitless searching... I am having a very specific issue understanding the way 'bytes' and hexadecimal content is handled in Python 3.2. I KNOW I'm misunderstanding, but can't seem to find the correct path.

My ultimate goal is to use the python serial module to transmit a sequence of bytes. Some bytes are static and won't change. Others are supposed to vary from 0-255 in value. These all need to be smushed together and transmitted at once. (These are instructions to a programmable display. The code contains fixed instructions to set BG colour, followed by a byte each for R, G and B values. I am trying to cycle through colour intensities in a loop to test, but later I'll want to be able to do this for practical functions on the display).

A complete static transmission, tested working successfully, might be as follows:

```
ser.write(b'\xAA\x11\x05\x00\x00\x00\xc3')  #this works great
```

Similarly, I can smush them together, i.e:

```
ser.write(b'\xAA\x11\x05' + b'\x00\x00\x00\xc3')  #also works great
```

Now if I want to take one of those three zero-value bytes, and replace it with a variable, it all goes pear-shaped. After much experimentation I ended up with something which allegedly converted the integer variable of a For loop into a type compatible with concatenation to the above series of bytes:

```
SET_BG_COLOR = b'\xAA\x03\x03'
for r in range(0,255):
            red = hex(r).encode('utf-8')
            blue = hex(255-r).encode('utf-8')
            ser.write(SET_BG_COLOR + blue + b'\x00' + red + b'\xC3') #BGR format
```

The hex(integer).encode('utf-8') was the only method so far which didn't just throw an error about being unable to concatenate to the other stuff I'm trying to shove down the serial connection. But it doesn't work, and when looking at the results:

```
>>> x = b'\05'
>>> x
b'\x05'
>>> y = hex(5).encode('utf-8')
>>> y
b'0x5'
>>> type(x)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> type(y)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> x + y
b'\x050x5'   #(this is what I get)
>>> z = b'\05'
>>> x + z
b'\x05\x05'  #(this is what I want)
>>>
```

Looks like, although it lets me concatenate... it's a binary representation of string data, or somesuch? So will let me concatenate but it's not true hex values? Have I missed a blindingly obvious way to go from x=255 to x= b'\FF'? Or is my whole approach just the wrong way to do this? -_- thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing Python byte literal syntax here; you do not need to generate the literal syntax, just the byte value; the `bytes()` type accepts a sequence of *integers* too:

```
>>> bytes([255])
b'\xff'
```

Applied to your code:

```
SET_BG_COLOR = b'\xAA\x03\x03'
for r in range(0,255):
    red = bytes([r])
    blue = bytes([255 - r])
    ser.write(SET_BG_COLOR + blue + b'\x00' + red + b'\xC3') #BGR format
```

or, simpler still:

```
SET_BG_COLOR = [0xAA, 0x03, 0x03]
for r in range(0,255):
    ser.write(bytes(SET_BG_COLOR + [r, 0x00, 255 - r, 0xC3])) #BGR format
```

using literal hex integer notation.

Demo for `r = 10`:

```
>>> SET_BG_COLOR = [0xAA, 0x03, 0x03]
>>> r = 10
>>> bytes(SET_BG_COLOR + [r, 0x00, 255 - r, 0xC3])
b'\xaa\x03\x03\n\x00\xf5\xc3'
```

The `hex()` function outputs 4 characters per byte; starting with a literal `0x` followed by the hex representation of the integer number. Encoded to UTF8 that's still 4 bytes, `b'\x30\x78\x30\x31'` for the integer value `10`, for example, versus `b'\x10'` for the actual byte you wanted.

Comment: Also note for Python 2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901706/the-bytes-type-in-python-2-7-and-pep-358

Comment: THANK YOU. This was driving me nuts. Have a nice, colour-cycling display on my desk right now :)

Comment: Hmm. It actually gives a hint right here in IDLE: if you type "bytes(" the popup menu says "() bytes(iterable_of_ints) -> bytes"... should've clicked that "iterable" implied I could use single-item lists. -_- Originally I was typing things like "bytes(5)" and wondering why I was getting 5 empty bytes out the other side!