# Python Byte to List

Tags: python, list, byte

I am using redis.get method and it's returns me byte.

In redis ı have a list like that:

```
[
    "ADA/USD",
    "ADA/USDT",
    "ALGO/USD",
    "ATOM/USD"
]
```

When get this list inside of my script with redis.get

It's return me

```
b'["ADA/USD","ADA/USDT","ALGO/USD","ATOM/USD"]'
```

How can I convert to a "Byte" to "List" ?

Comment: Maybe help you , you see this ? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658193/python3-how-to-make-a-bytes-object-from-a-list-of-integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658193/python3-how-to-make-a-bytes-object-from-a-list-of-integers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import json

json.loads(b'["ADA/USD","ADA/USDT","ALGO/USD","ATOM/USD"]'.decode())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the `bytes` to a `list` - you could convert it to a string object and then split (after replacement) -

```py
x = b'["ADA/USD","ADA/USDT","ALGO/USD","ATOM/USD"]'.decode().replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(',')
```

**Output**

```
# print(x)
['"ADA/USD"', '"ADA/USDT"', '"ALGO/USD"', '"ATOM/USD"']
# print(type(x))
<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
x = b'["ADA/USD","ADA/USDT","ALGO/USD","ATOM/USD"]'
my_list = eval(x)
print(my_list) # ['ADA/USD', 'ADA/USDT', 'ALGO/USD', 'ATOM/USD']
print(type(my_list)) # <class 'list'>
```

Note: this could be dangerous if you're accepting a user input and then evaluating: check first that x is not something like `__import__('shutil').rmtree('/')`