# Use cases for bytearray

Tags: python, arrays

Can you point out a scenario in which Python's [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray) is useful? Is it simply a non-unicode string that supports list methods which can be easily achieved anyway with `str` objects?

I understand some think of it as "the mutable string". However, when would I need such a thing? And: unlike strings or lists, I am strictly limited to ascii, so in any case I'd prefer the others, is that not true?

Comment: for instance when you are working with network....

Comment: ...or whenever else you need a sequence of bytes...

Comment: I am working with network. I am using `deque` for my sequence of bytes, as it is efficient from both ends. In what way `bytearray` is an advantage in these cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bach,

`bytearray` is a mutable block of memory. To that end, you can push arbitrary bytes into it and manage your memory allocations carefully. While many Python programmers never worry about memory use, there are those of us that do. I manage buffer allocations in high load network operations. There are numerous applications of a mutable array -- too many to count.

It isn't correct to think of the `bytearray` as a mutable string. It isn't. It is an array of bytes. Strings have a specific structure. `bytearray`s do not. You can interpret the bytes however you wish. A string is one way. Be careful though, there are many corner cases when using Unicode strings. `ASCII` strings are comparatively trivial. Modern code runs across borders. Hence, Python's rather complete Unicode-based string classes.

A `bytearray` reveals memory allocated by the buffer protocol. This very rich protocol is the foundation of Python's interoperation with C and enables numpy and other direct access memory technologies. In particular, it allows memory to be easily structured into multi-dimensional arrays in either C or FORTRAN order.

You may never have to use a `bytearray`.

Anon, Andrew

Answer (score 2):

`deque` seems to need much more space than `bytearray`.

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(collections.deque(range(256)))
1336
>>> sys.getsizeof(bytearray(range(256)))
293
```

I Guess this is because of the layout.

If you need samples using bytearray I suggest [searching the online code with nullege](http://nullege.com/codes/search?cq=bytearray).

`bytearray` also has one more advantage: you do not need to import anything for that. This means that people will use it - whether it makes sense or not.

Further reading about bytearray: [the bytes type in python 2.7 and PEP-358](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901706/the-bytes-type-in-python-2-7-and-pep-358)