# python received byte array length change from bluetooth

Tags: android, python, bluetooth, arrays

I used android to parse a long variable into 6 bytes, which is received by python code through bluetooth on my computer to put it together. On the android side, it shows that it sends 6 bytes.

If the byte array sent from android for example is "F�I��", python print received byte array is exactly the same "F�I��". But len(data) = 12, not 6. It looks like each "�" has a length of 3. Anyone have a clue? How do I interpret it correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of python are you using? Python 2 and 3 handle bytestrings very differently. Can you share the code?

Comment: I use 2.7. Below is the code. Also I found that each "�" is a negative byte, probably something to do with that. I'm digging into it.                              
{
print("received [%s]" % data) # print: F�I��
print len(data)               # print: 12
l = 0
for i in range(len(data)):
 print ord(data[i])
 l = l<<8
 l = l + ord(rawdata[i])
print l
}

Comment: Are you receiving the data with a python socket? This looks like encoding problem, see if this makes sense to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901706/the-bytes-type-in-python-2-7-and-pep-358

Comment: @RafaelBarros Thanks for the hint. Just found that it's the java problem on the android side. The weird length change happened when I convert a byte array to a String.