# creating a byte string in python

Tags: python-2.7, cmd

I'm trying to create a byte string, but it seems to be just a regular character string.  What am I doing wrong here?

[image: example]

```
byteStr = b'some string'
byteStr #'some string'
utfStr = 'some string'.encode('utf-8')
utfStr #'some string'
byteStr == utfStr #True
```

Comment: Your bytestring is created correctly; just because it's equal to a charstring doesn't mean that's wrong. I won't answer because I don't know how bytestrings work but comparing bytestrings and charstrings will (usually) give `True`.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino updated, i was expecting the print of byteStr to show a b before the first quote, and the equivalency test to fail

Comment: @HyperNeutrino i see, also, when i run type(byteStr) i get back <type 'str'>.  Is that correct?

Comment: @anonymousPerson....thanks for the random downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to create a byte array in Python 2, it's called a `bytearray`. [Python 2 does not have a `byte string`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901706/the-bytes-type-in-python-2-7-and-pep-358). [The `b` in front of the str is ignored in Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6269785/57191), meaning `'hello' == b'hello'`

Try this:

```
>>> f = b'f'
>>> type(f)
<type 'str'>
```

Now, it's important to remember that `u'f' == 'f'`:

```
>>> h = u'f'
>>> f == h
True
>>> type(h)
>>> <type 'unicode'>
```

Comment: Ahhh, I see. The tutorial I'm following is using python3 which explains the difference.  Thank you!

Comment: as a quick follow up question, why would type(uftStr) in my example return <type 'str'> instead of <type 'unicode'>?  It seems as though the .encode('utf-8') function didnt work